# C# converting from float to hexstring via IEEE 754 and back to float

Tags: c#

I need to convert a `float` value to a hexadecimal string and back again. The online [IEEE 754 Converter](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) allows me to do that. Here is my attempt to implement the conversion:

```
unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
{
    float f = 0.0023984962F;
    long l = *((long*)&f);
    float r = *((float*)&l);

    Console.WriteLine("{0} <-> {1:X} <-> {1:F1} <-> {2:F1}", f, l, r);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

My questions:

1. With the float `0.0023984962` the expected result is `0x3B1D3017` but my code prints `0x22CB20C3B1D3017`. What am I doing wrong?
2. How can I save the output in a variable?

Comment: A good reminder why `unsafe` is really unsafe.  Use BitConverter.GetBytes() instead.

Answer (score 4):

To be able to convert both ways you need two functions. You have a bug in your code where you cast a 32 bit floating point number (`float`) to a 64 bit integer (`long`). Because your code is `unsafe` this bug is not caught by the compiler.

However, using `unsafe` code performs very well so here is code that works:

```
unsafe string ToHexString(float f) {
  var i = *((int*) &f);
  return "0x" + i.ToString("X8");
}

unsafe float FromHexString(string s) {
  var i = Convert.ToInt32(s, 16);
  return *((float*) &i);
}
```

To avoid the problems of `unsafe` code you can also use a `BitConverter` which will check the size of the intermediate byte buffers for you.

```
string ToHexString(float f) {
  var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(f);
  var i = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
  return "0x" + i.ToString("X8");
}

float FromHexString(string s) {
  var i = Convert.ToInt32(s, 16);
  var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);
  return BitConverter.ToSingle(bytes, 0);
}
```

You can now convert both ways:

```
var hexString = ToHexString(0.0023984962F);
var f = FromHexString(hexString);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `int`, not `long` when converting `float`, since `float` (aka `Single`) is 32-bit value (unlike `double` which is 64-bit):

```
unsafe static void Main(string[] args)
{
    float f = 0.0023984962F;
    int l = *((int*)&f); // int here: 32-bit float into 32-bit integer
    float r = *((float*)&l);

    // Let's save the result in the variable
    String result = String.Format("{0} <-> {1:X} <-> {1:F1} <-> {2:F1}", f, l, r);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

However, a better approach is to use `BitConverter` that's specially designed to that role and avoid *unsafe* routine:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  float f = 0.0023984962F;

  uint l = BitConverter.ToUInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(f), 0);
  float r = BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(l), 0);

  // Let's save the result in the variable
  String result = String.Format("{0} <-> {1:X} <-> {1:F1} <-> {2:F1}", f, l, r);

  Console.WriteLine(result);
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: I was trying to convert a double and couldn't work out why it wasn't working. Casting the double to a float first fixed my issue.

Comment: @Moon Waxing: `double` is **64-bit** value, that's why when working with `double` you should use `long` (or `ulong`)

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question you can use string variable to store output like:

```
String output = String.Format("{0} <-> {1:X} <-> {1:F1} <-> {2:F1}", f, l, r);
```