# How do I convert a floating point to hexadecimal in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, floating-point, hex

Example: The float value is -1580.719 and I need to convert it to hex in VB.NET (Value in hex should  output: C4C59704).

Comment: Hello!  Did you try searching StackOverflow for [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26011546/float-point-to-hex-in-c-sharp) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449339/c-sharp-converting-from-float-to-hexstring-via-ieee-754-and-back-to-float)?  I think this has been answered here before.

Comment: Note that `-1580.719` would be encoded as `C4C59702`. The value you gave, i.e., `C4C59704` actually encodes `-1580.7192` as a single-precision IEEE74 floating point number.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments. I found how to do it! Example below. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found how to do it:

```
Dim var As Single = Single.Parse("-1580.719")
Dim varArray() As Byte = BitConverter.GetBytes(var)
Array.Reverse(varArray)
Dim result As String = BitConverter.ToString(varArray).Replace("-", "")
```

Value of result is:

```
C4C59702
```

Comment: You may already be aware but you should accept your own answer so everyone knows that you don't need any more help without opening the question, although I think that you have to wait a while to do so.

Comment: Yeah, it shows the message: "You can accept your own answer in 2 days".

Comment: I guess they do that because they figure that someone else may be able to come up with a better answer than the person who needed to ask the question in the first place.