# Print and parse hexfloat in .NET (C#/VB.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, floating-point

In c++, one can use `std::cout << std::hexfloat << someFloatValue` to print floating point values in base 16, instead of the usual base 10. For example, 0.09375 (i.e. 3/32) would be printed as **"0x1.8p-4"**

**It should not print "0x3DC00000"! This is simply be type-punning the float to an int and printing that in hexadecimal. That's not what I'm looking for!**
I am looking specifically for the [C++ "hexfloat" format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed).

I cannot find anything similar in .NET. I need to print some floating point vaules from a VB.NET program (but that's not required, C# works too) that are later read by a C++ program. Ideally, I would also like to be able to parse those back into my VB.NET program.

How do I correctly print hexfloats from .NET? I would rather avoid rolling my own algorithm, if there is already something in the framework. If not, I would like to avoid platform-dependent code, e.g. plonking the float into a union (`[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)] struct`) and inspecting the underlying bits through that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# converting from float to hexstring via IEEE 754 and back to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35449339/c-sharp-converting-from-float-to-hexstring-via-ieee-754-and-back-to-float)

Comment: @Piglet No. Please see the example output that I gave in the first paragraph.

Comment: Something like `var bits = BitConverter.SingleToInt32Bits(d); return $"{(bits >> 63 == 0 ? "+" : "-")}0x1{bits & 0x7fffff:X}p{(bits >> 23) & 0x7FFFFF:X}";` see https://dotnetfiddle.net/4uZDw3

Comment: Why does the C++ program insist on an esoteric format like this vs. an integer hex representation?  Do you have any influence with the C++ side?

Comment: @Charlieface Your example outputs "-0x1400000p7FFF7B" for the given value -3/32.

Comment: @Craig It's not esoteric at all. It's just scientific notation (e.g. "9.375E-2") but in base 16 instead. This allows exact representation of the stored value, without the risk of truncated decimal places messing with the restored value.

Comment: This is the first I've heard of it.  I suppose there may be domains where it's common, but when I've needed to smuggle floats from C++ into VB via text, I've dumped the integer representation of the bit pattern.

Comment: @Craig That's one way, but it's not platform-independent. Specifically, the endianess of the platforms' int vs float representation might not be the same, and one of the platforms might not even use support IEEE 754 floats.

Comment: Potential lack of IEEE floats is significant and would tend more toward justifying something like this.

Comment: I was guessing all over the place, I knew it didn't work properly, but you get the point: `BitConverter.SingleToInt32Bits` gets you the bits, then you need to shift the bits around to get the format right

Comment: @Craig: Note that this format isn't a language-specific feature of C/C++: it's described in the IEEE 754 standard (in §5.12.3 of IEEE 754-2019, to be precise), and supported by a number of other languages, including Java, Python, and Julia.